# login failure in prodcution mode

Tags: symfony, authentication, production-environment

I am using symfony 5.4.4.
I encounter a problem when I try to connect a user without launching the php server (I want to work in production mode).

I used make:user commands to create the User entity. Then I used the make:auth and make:registration-form commands to generate the login and registration forms.
everything works perfectly when I run the symfony server with the symfony serve command. On localhost:8000 I am able to register and login users with no problem.
I then followed the symfony documentation on deployment as I want my application to run in a server accessible from a private network. I then ran the commands:

- composer require symfony/requirements-checker to check
- composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
  Then I updated the .env file
  APP_ENV=prod
  APP_DEBUG=0
  before clearing the cache with: php bin/console cache:clear
  And finally I added rewrite rules with the command: composer require symfony/apache-pack.

now I access my application from any computer (example: http://localhost/myproject/public/user/4) in the network and I navigate without problems on the links.
However, when I try to login a user, it doesn't work.
And when I try to enter one, it works.

In summary, the login works on localhost:8000 but does not work on localhost/myproject/public while all other forms work.
Can you help me ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Give this a try.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253287/symfony-5-4-securitybundle-cant-login-after-register/71270988#71270988

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? Do you get a 500 http code response ? Do you have any log by the server ?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "enter one" in" And when I try to enter one, it works."
P.S. switch to DEV mode and take a look into a `/_profiler`. Analyze responses and redirects

Comment: sorry my english is not good !
I don't get any error code. when I submit the form, it reloads and that's it! there is no error message. it does not login the User but returns the login form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK !
I added the method below into my App/src/Authenticator.php class
Notice : it does not work without the return type "bool" of the function

```
public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }
```

I hope it will be useful to someone!
Thanks to all and especially to Cerad for the link !